# How does Closed Line Integral depend on the Origin?

Tags: integration, line-integrals

I found this in Schaum's outline of Advanced Calculus stating:
[Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC4Vc.jpg)

in case (b),

For a closed curve PQRSP not surrounding the origin, $\phi=\phi_{0}$ at $P$ and $\phi=\phi_{0}$ after a complete circuit back to $P$. In this case, the line integral equals $\int_{\phi_{0}}^{\phi_{0}} d \phi=0$.

How is it possible? when

in case (a),

For a closed curve ABCDA surrounding the origin, $\phi=0$ at $A$ and $\phi=2\pi$ after a complete circuit back to $A$. In this case, the line integral equals $\int_{0}^{2\pi} d \phi=2\pi$.

Comment: Hi Shubhadeep. Can you write a short sentence, defining exactly what is $\phi$ in your story? You may need to refer to landmarks in the world of your problem.

Comment: @311411 thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the question with an image describing $\psi$s, you can check it out

Comment: Ok. So your picture makes it clear that the object $\phi$, whatever it is, has a close relationship with the origin. One might even say $\phi$ depends on the origin.

Comment: A big part of the problem here is that we really shouldn't write $d\phi$, because that seems to suggest $\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_0} d\phi = \phi(\phi_0) - \phi(\phi_0) = 0$. In reality $d\phi$ is a closed (but not exact!) differential form, so it's value can differ from what you expect over a closed loop by $2\pi k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @311411 as this user says, $d \phi$ implicitly depends on the location of the origin. It is what is often called the "angle form" and, for a closed curve, it measures how many times the closed curve wraps around the origin.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Shubhadeep not in the space provided. This sort of thing will make perfect sense if you study differential forms. The best I can say is that you should notice there has to be a point where $\phi$ isn't defined (the point you measure angle from). It's this point that means integrating over a closed loop doesn't always give you $0$.

Comment: Roughly because the punctured plane is not "simply connected." A curve that wraps twice around the point where you punctured the plane is fundamentally different from a curve that wraps around it once. The form $d\phi$ can detect this.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins but, according to the given picture, the region bounded by the curve looks like simply connected region. So how does the curve wrap around the region here?

Comment: Yes, the region bounded by the curve is, but the intersection of that region with the domain of $\phi$ is not. That makes all the difference.